# spring boot 2.0.0.M4 ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm facing this problem with a simple Spring Boot 2 project with juste 2 repositories

https://github.com/mmaryo/spring-boot-2-mongo-dbref-example

```
    @Test
    public void testMongoDbRef() {
     AccountEntity account = new AccountEntity();
     account.setName("Github");
     account = accountRepository.save(account).block();

     CustomerEntity customer = new CustomerEntity(); 
     customer.setFirstName("Victor");
     customer.setLastName("Hugo");
     customer.setAccount(account);
     customerRepository.save(customer).block();
    }
```

This code throws this error :

> Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient not present
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient

I use mongo v3.4.3

Have you an idea for resolve this issue ?

Comment: Have you checked this dependency in pom file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Reactive Streams MongoDB driver, use `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive` as starter (instead of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`).

The resolved dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-async</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, but with that I have this error, any idea ? Caused by: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'reactiveStreamsMongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBRefCodecProvider       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBRefCodecProvider

Comment: Check your dependency versions. The MongoDB driver on your side probably requires a version upgrade.